# Indexes for references in same table

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
person_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
parent_person_id INTEGER REFERENCES person(person_id),
CONSTRAINT PK_person_id PRIMARY KEY (person_id)
);
```

Is there need to create index on parent_person_id column or it is created automatically?

Comment: parent_person_id NOT NULL??? Wha...

Comment: @strawberry , yup, sry. Stupid mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create the index on `parent_person_id`. Indexes are required on the referenced column, not the referencing one.

Also, be aware that there are some restrictions on creating same-table relationships. At the MySQL website, on the section on [foreign-key relationships](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html), it reads, "If ON UPDATE CASCADE or ON UPDATE SET NULL recurses to update the same table it has previously updated during the cascade, it acts like RESTRICT.

This means that you cannot use self-referential `ON UPDATE CASCADE` or `ON UPDATE SET NULL` operations. This is to prevent infinite loops resulting from cascaded updates."

This is a known limitation of MySQL and you should be aware to prevent apparently nonsensical errors.

Answer (score 0):

foreign key indexed automatically in only InnoDB. In referencing table, there must be a column 
where the foreign key columns are listed as the first columns in the same order.
Such an index is created on the referencing table automatically if it does not exist.